# What type of array should I use to combine numerical values and string values and have the ability to sort them in octave/matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, octave

I'm trying to link numerical (octave/matlab) values in an array to string values in the array how can I go about doing this.  The reason I'm trying to do this is to sort the array based on the numerical values.

Example:

> array=[1,2,'filename1';3,4,'filename2';5,6,'filename3'] ***(I know this is incorrect and will give an error)***

This is what I'm trying to get it to look like so I can sort based on the first or the second column and have the third column be "linked" / follow the sort.  ***(Please note the numbers will not be a sequential sequence like 1,2,3... I just used that as an example)***

```
1,2,filename1
3,4,filename2
5,6,filename3
```

If I sort the first numerical column in descending order it should look like this

> 5,6,filename3
>   3,4,filename2
>   1,2,filename1

How can I go about doing this and still get the values of the array individually?
Example:
**array(1,1)** would be **5** 
and **array(3,3)** would be **filename1**

If you want to know, I plan on creating a playlist of wavfile names based on this sort.
Ps: I'm using Octave/Matlab

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 separate arrays, one with 2 columns of number and one with strings. When you sort the first array based on the first number, the function will return both the sorted list as well as the reordered indices. You can use the reordered indices to rearrange the strings.
It would be something like this:

```
[sort_list, indx] = sort(array1, 1);
array_string = array_strings[indx];
```

I don't think the access in that way is possible. Maybe you can do something similar with cells but I would be more expensive than using 2 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use  a [cell arrray](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). You then sort using [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
>> myCell = {1, 2, 'filename1';
             3, 4, 'filename2';
             5, 6, 'filename3'};

>> array = flipud(sortrows(myCell, 1)) %// "1" => col. "flipud" => descending
ans = 
    [5]    [6]    'filename3'
    [3]    [4]    'filename2'
    [1]    [2]    'filename1'

>> array(1,1)
ans = 
    [5]

>> array(3,3)
ans = 
    'filename1'
```

Comment: I get an error
error: sortrows: only cell arrays of character strings may be sorted

Comment: @RickT In my example with numbers and strings (paste the exact code) it works

Comment: Then it must be octave 3.8.1, not being fully compatible with some of matlabs functions